# Subtracting items from a text file

Tags: c#, combobox, text-files

When the first option is selected in a combo box I wish for my program to subtract consecutive strings from the one before.

Eg. The second value from the first,the third from the second, the fourth from the third and so on to the limit of 40.

I tried this but it just reads the actual list with no calculation

```
private void comboBoxOptions_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)   
{
    if (comboBoxOptions.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        string population = @"U:\My Documents\4.Bus App\Assignment 5\irishPopulation.txt";
        const int SIZE = 40;
        int[] numbers2 = new int[SIZE];
        int index = 0;
        StreamReader inputFile = new StreamReader(population);
        while (index < numbers2.Length && !inputFile.EndOfStream)
        {
            numbers2[index] = int.Parse(inputFile.ReadLine());
            index++;
            }

        textBoxAnswer.Text = File.ReadAllText(@"U:\My Documents\4.Bus App\Assignment 5\irishPopulation.txt"); //Puts file in textbox
        textBoxAnswer.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical; //Gives text a scroll bar
        inputFile.Close();
    }
```

Comment: You never change the content in the text file.

Comment: And there is no logic whatsoever that indicates you are subtracting anything from anything.

Comment: How do I subtract consecutive numbers in the text file I have if  the first combo box option is selected

Comment: First read all text lines into an array/list, then use a for loop and subtract  index 1 from index 0 > subtract index 2 from index 1 ... so on. Add each outcome to a new array/list ... populate answer as wanted.

Comment: I hav populated a list with values.. How do i then use foreach to pull the string values out and then use index one from index 0